# Groovy cannot resolve Classes from other Groovy files

Tags: java, groovy, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to create a groovy context programatically and add multiple scripts to it.

This is a simplified version but it should explain the problem:

**test/Helper.groovy**

```
package test

class Helper {
    static void help() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

**test/Test.groovy**

```
package test

class Test {
    static void test() {
        Helper.help()
    }
}
```

The context is build with this java code:

```java
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(Runner.class.getClassLoader(), new Binding(), CompilerConfiguration.DEFAULT);
        
        load(shell, "/test/Test.groovy");
        load(shell, "/test/Helper.groovy");
    }

    private static void load(GroovyShell shell, String name) throws IOException {
        try(var script = Runner.class.getResourceAsStream(name)) {
            String scriptSrc = new String(script.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            shell.parse(scriptSrc, name);
        }
    }
}
```

**!!! Intentionally I load the scripts in an arbitrary order.**

---

If I run this code locally everything works fine.

Running this code inside SAP Commerce (essentially a tomcat with spring and other stuff) throws an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Test.groovy: 5: Apparent variable 'Helper' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
You attempted to use a method 'Helper' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.

        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:292) ~[groovy-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$IPrimaryClassNodeOperation.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:979) ~[groovy-4.0.2.jar:2.5.14]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:692) ~[groovy-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:666) ~[groovy-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:373) ~[groovy-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.lambda$parseClass$2(GroovyClassLoader.java:316) ~[groovy-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.compute(StampedCommonCache.java:163) ~[groovy-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.getAndPut(StampedCommonCache.java:154) ~[groovy-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:314) ~[groovy-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:553) ~[groovy-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:566) ~[groovy-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:620) ~[groovy-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:624) ~[groovy-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
```

Since we have more groovy scripts in our environment and by the way we designed the application I cannot put them in the right order.

---

What can cause this behavior from groovy?

I am not aware of something like a security manager ect. enabled in the tomcat.

Tested with groovy 2.5.14

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to have a singleton of GroovyShell for a context because parsing/compiling groovy takes a lot of time.

---

How to run your code correctly from java:

make folder structure for groovy classes:

```
/groovy-root
  /test
    Helper.groovy
    Test.groovy
```

package name must correspond to a folder inside some root folder that we are going to add as a classpath.

then java code will look like:

```java
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;

public class A{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(A.class.getClassLoader());
        shell.getClassLoader().addClasspath("./groovy-root");
        // this line will load all required classes to execute script
        shell.evaluate("test.Test.test()"); 
    }
}
```

---

I'm not familiar with SAP, but there is an existing groovy context in there, just add `"./groovy-root"` folder into a classpath and you are all set.